# Best approach or is it possible to create this list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, form

We have a department that has requested a complex list for creating a Request for quotes and I just want to see if you guys think its possible and maybe give us some starters on where to look.

They want a form that people can request a quote. We have 10 fields (Mixture or text and drop down's) that they need to complete about the product but we need to be able to add multiples of those fields depending on how many units they need.

I was assuming that we may have to have several list with a unique identifier that link them together, but not sure how to link them all together or launch a new item in another list from an existing form.

These forms will all be on the same site.

Also we only have sharepoint 2010 foundation (free) so I just want to make sure that I will not be spending lots of time and then find out I need another version. I saw that in infopath you can create a repeating section, but because we have foundation we are unable to import that form so is there a way to duplicate that sort of feature?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to SharePoint Enterprise to receive the InfoPath Forms Service that you need in order to get the Request for Quotes form with multiple selection listbox that you specified.

As far as Foundation is limited to, you can create a List Form Web Part to embed a List, of your custom columns/fields, that you can specify the Request for Quote. Where the multiple selections come into place, have a multiple lines of text for your multiple selections and in the description describe what is a valid answer.